# Using same path for @GET and @POST

Tags: java, rest, restful-url, restful-architecture

In java RESTfull service can I define two methods in same path differentiate by http calling method.

EG : first method using GET and Second one using POST

```
@GET
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response getFile(@Context HttpServletRequest req,@PathParam("search") final String search,Map<Object, Object> input) {
....}

@Post
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response getFile(@Context HttpServletRequest req,@PathParam("search") final String search) {
....}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotation is just a decorator for the given method. The core principle is , it should not stop original structure of java classes. So it is perfectly legal to have multiple handler in single file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly valid to have separate handlers for different methods at the same path.